# For an $f:\omega_1 \to \omega_1$, how to prove $\alpha = f(\alpha)$ for uncountably many $\alpha$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My homework question reads:

> Let $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal, and let $f:\omega_1 \to \omega_1$ be s.t.
>
> - If $\alpha < \beta < \omega_1$, then $f(\alpha) < f(\beta)$.
> - If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $$f(\alpha) = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} f(\beta).$$
>
> a) Prove that $\alpha \leq f(\alpha)$ $\forall \alpha < \omega_1$.
>
> b) Prove that $\alpha = f(\alpha)$ for uncountably many $\alpha < \omega_1$.

I've done problem a) (by transfinite induction), but I'm not quite sure how I should do b). It seems obvious that the easiest way to prove this would be to show that $\alpha \geq f(\alpha)$ for an uncountable subset of $\omega_1$, but I'm sort of stuck as to which subset. Could anyone give me a little hint?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Given any $\beta<\omega_1$, consider the supremum $\alpha$ of the (non-decreasing by part a) sequence $\beta, f(\beta), f(f(\beta)),\dots$.  Show that $\beta\leq\alpha<\omega_1$ and $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) But would this show that $f(\alpha) = \alpha$ for *uncountably* many $\alpha$? Wouldn't it just show the existence of such an $\alpha$?

Comment: @Maethor It shows the existence of such an $\alpha$ above any prescribed countable ordinal $\beta$.  So yes, it shows the existence of uncountably many such $\alpha$'s.